How to show that $\{ Y = + \infty \} \subset \{ E[Y | \mathcal{G}] = +\infty \}$
Let $Y$ be a non-negative random variable, and let $\mathcal{G}$ be a sub-$\sigma$-algebra. The conditional expectation $E[Y \mid \mathcal{G}]$ is defined as the $\mathcal{G}$-measurable random variable satisfying:
$$
\int_A E[Y \mid \mathcal{G}] \, dP = \int_A Y \, dP \quad \text{for all } A \in \mathcal{G}.
$$
It is required to show that:
$$
\{ Y = +\infty \} \subset \{ E[Y \mid \mathcal{G}] = +\infty \} \quad \text{almost surely.}
$$
My Attempt

If $Y = +\infty$ on a set $A \in \mathcal{G}$, then the integral $\int_A Y \, dP = +\infty$.
By the definition of $E[Y \mid \mathcal{G}]$, it must hold that:
$$
   \int_A E[Y \mid \mathcal{G}] \, dP = \int_A Y \, dP.
   $$
Since the right-hand side is $+ \infty$, it seems intuitive that $E[Y \mid \mathcal{G}] = +\infty$ almost surely on $A$.

However, I am struggling to provide a rigorous argument that directly connects $Y = +\infty$ to $E[Y \mid \mathcal{G}] = +\infty$.
Here's the best I could provide: without loss of generality $P \left(\{ Y = +\infty\} \right) > 0$ and it holds that
$$
+\infty = \int_A Y \cdot \mathbb{1}_{\{ Y = +\infty \}} \ dP = \int_A E \left[ Y \cdot \mathbb{1}_{\{ Y = +\infty \}} | \mathcal{G} \right] \ dP \leq \int_A E \left[ Y| \mathcal{G} \right] \ dP
$$
Wouldn't this prove that $\{ Y = +\infty \} \subset \{ E[Y | \mathcal{G}] = +\infty \}$ and that $P(\{ E[Y | \mathcal{G}] = +\infty \}) = 1 ?$ I found this terribly suspiscious, I must have missed something!
Could someone provide a detailed proof or explanation?
Additional Context
The problem is from Probability Essentials by Jacod and Protter, specifically from the chapter on conditional expectation. The main challenge is understanding how the behavior of $Y$ (when it takes infinite values) translates to the conditional expectation $E[Y \mid \mathcal{G}]$, particularly in terms of measure-theoretic rigor.
For those who are perplexed about how to define the conditional expectation for measurable non negative functions not necessarily integrable here's a brief explanation.
You use an approximation argument
$$
E[Y | \mathcal{G}]= \lim_{m \to +\infty }E[m \wedge Y | \mathcal{G}].
$$
Notice that the property of conditional expectation is tested against non negative functions:
$$
E[Y \cdot X] = E[ E[Y | \mathcal{G}] \cdot X ] \quad \forall X \geq 0 \, \, X \ \text{measurable}.
$$
To prove the well-posedness definition and the property of conditional expectation, just apply Beppo-Levi like there's no tomorrow!
Any help or clarification would be greatly appreciated!

You start with: If $Y = +\infty$ on a set $A \in \mathcal G$. The problem starts there. $Y=\infty$ need  not be  $\mathcal G$ measurable and you cannot take  $A \in \mathcal G$.

Let $A:=\{Y=+\infty\}$ and $B:=\{\Bbb E[Y\mid\mathcal G]=+\infty\}$.
For every $n\ge1$, we have
$\Bbb E[Y\mid\mathcal G]\ge\Bbb E[Y\,\mathbf 1_{\{Y\ge n\}}\mid\mathcal G]$ $\Bbb P$-a.s., and since $B$ is a $\mathcal G$-measurable event we get that, $\Bbb P$-a.s.,
\begin{align*}
\frac 1n\,\underbrace{\Bbb E[Y\mid\mathcal G]\,\mathbf1_{\Omega\setminus B}}_{<+\infty}
&\ge\frac1n\,\Bbb E[Y\,\mathbf 1_{\{Y\ge n\}\setminus B}\mid\mathcal G]\\[.4em]
&\ge\Bbb P(\{Y\ge n\}\setminus B\mid\mathcal G)\\[.4em]
&\ge\Bbb P(A\setminus B\mid\mathcal G).
\end{align*}
It follows by taking $n\to+\infty$ that
$$\Bbb P(A\setminus B\mid\mathcal G)=0,\quad\text{$\mathbb P$-almost surely.}$$
Hence $\Bbb P(A\setminus B)=0$, i.e., $A\subseteq B$ holds $\Bbb P$-almost surely.
